# Why under specific enviroments UNICODE characters trigger an EncodeError and at others not?

Tags: python

I am making a Python project that needs to work with Greek characters print, edit and return strings.

On my main PC that has the Greek language installed everything runs fine but when I am running on my English laptop the same program with the same version of python an encode error is triggered. Especially this one:

> EncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2:
>   ordinal not                         in range(128)

The error happens due to this code

```
my_string = "Δίας"
print(my_string)
```

Why is this happening and what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? The Unicode behaviour changed quite a bit between versions 2 and 3.

Comment: afaik the terminal you are printing to can cause this error as well ... (ie pycharms terminal handles unicode fine... but the normal system terminal window doesnt like non-ascii characters) ... python2 attempts to implicitly encode/decode strings when appropriate, which leads to all kind of wonkyness ... if you are printing for logfile reasons, i recommend always printing the repr instead of the item

Comment: If you are working on different environments, I suspect this may be due to the way the different terminal emulators are configured to support unicode. Some default to only ascii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this happening? You are using Python 2 and although it supports Unicode, it makes you jump through a few more hoops explicitly than Python 3 does. The string you provide contains characters that fall outside the normal first 128 ASCII characters, which is what is causing the problem.

The `print` statement tries to encode the string as standard `ascii`, but it runs into characters it doesn't understand and by that point, it does not know what encoding the characters are supposed to be in. You might think this is obvious: "the same encoding the file is in!" or "always UTF-8!", but Python 2 wants you to make it explicit.

What do you need to do to fix it? One solution would be to use Python 3 and not worry about it, if all you need is a quick solution. Python 3 really is the way forward at this point and using Python 2 makes you solve problems that many Python programmers today don't have to solve (although they should be able to, in the end).

If you want to keep using Python 2, you should change your code to this:

```
# coding=utf-8
my_string = u"Δίας"
print(my_string.encode('utf-8'))
```

The first line tells the interpreter explicitly what encoding the source file was written in. This helps your IDE as well, to make sure it is showing you the code correctly. The second line has the `u` in front of the string, telling Python `my_string` is in fact a unicode string. And the third line explicitly tells Python that you want the output to be `utf-8` encoded as well.

A more complete explanation of all this is here https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

If you're wondering why it works on your Greek computer, but not on your English computer - the default encoding on the Greek computer actually has the code points for the characters you're using, while the English encoding does not. This indicates that Python is clever enough to figure out that things are utf (and the string is a series of unicode code points), but by the time it needs to encode them, it doesn't know what encoding to use, as the standard (English) encoding doesn't have the characters in the string.